# How to go 1 level back for a directory path stored in a variable in perl

Tags: perl, unix

I am dynamically getting the path of a directory and it is getting stored in a variable. I need to go 1 level down and get the parent directory. Also, the path is a Windows path.
Basically , i am running perl on windows.
How to achieve this in perl ? Anything is fine - regular expression or any other way.
Please help!

For example :

Original directory path :

```
        my $dir = "C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir";
```

Output what is needed is :

```
        my $dir = "C:/mytest/mydata/mywork";
```

I need till parent directory "mywork" , not "mydir".

Can anybody help in writing code for the same ?

Second query :

I am having space in the directory path:

example :

```
      my $testdir = "C:/mytest own/mydata/mywork/mydir";
```

Notice, "mytest own" is one directory but with space.
Now, when i am trying to enter to use this variable to enter to this directory, i am unable to do so.

For query 1 , I tried the below piece of code :

@Ingo :

```
          #!/usr/bin/perl

          my $dir = "C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir";

          print "Input directory is : $dir\n";

          my $outdir = $dir . "/..";

          print "Output directory is :  $outdir";
```

Note : I need to accomplish this, without using any perl module.

@TLP : I tried using your cut-short method, the code is again copied, but it doesn't give the desired output.

```
        #!/usr/bin/perl

         use strict;
         use warnings;
         use File::Spec;

          my $str    = "C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir";
          my @dirs   = File::Spec->splitdir($str);        # parse directories                                    
          my $newdir = File::Spec->catdir(@dirs, File::Spec->updir());      # create new path
          print $newdir;
```

Output looks like : The output gets appended with /..

```
          C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir/..
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a module for manipulating a path is perhaps a safer option. [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec) has the convenient `splitdir` and `catdir` functions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

my $str    = "C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir";
my @dirs   = File::Spec->splitdir($str);        # parse directories
pop @dirs;                                      # remove top dir
my $newdir = File::Spec->catdir(@dirs);         # create new path
print $newdir;
```

Note that the new path will by default use path delimiters that your current system uses.

You can also do

```
my $newdir = File::Spec->catdir(@dirs, File::Spec->updir());
```

(`updir()` returns `..`) The output is the same on my system (Windows 7), which is to say

```
C:\mytest\mydata\mywork
```

I would have thought that it would be `C:\mytest\mydata\mywork\mydir\..`, but apparently the module abbreviated.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily give the parent. `mydir` could be a symlink. Not very likely on a Windows system, though.

Comment: @ikegami The logic is ambiguous there. You could want the parent of the symlink itself, but you could also want the parent of its target. Anyway, if you use `my $newdir = File::Spec->catdir(@dirs, File::Spec->updir())` the result is the same as above (in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

First, to get the parent directory, just append "/.."

```
$dir . "/.."
```

Second, are you using this in an external command or something? Then you must quote the path name, like in:

```
system "ls '$testdir'"
```

Otherwise, if you want to change directory in perl, the following should be fine:

```
chdir $testdir or die "Can't change to '$testdir' - $!"
```

Comment: For second query, i need to do "cd $testdir". I need to enter that directory.But, because of space , it is not entering and giving error.

Comment: Your first answer is not working. It is giving the output as : input directory : C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir
 output directory :C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir/..

Comment: So, why don't you just `chdir $testdir`, then?

Comment: @ShubhraGarg Even if you don't believe it, if d is a directory, then d/.. is its parent directory. Try it out.

Comment: I already tried, after trying I ma telling you that if double quotes is used then /d/.. doesn't work.

Comment: @TLP : I can't use any perl module. This must e done without any perl module.

Comment: So, what exactly keeps you from telling us what "didn't work"? How are we supposed to help if you don't tell what you want. You said you want the path name of the parent dir of $dir, and `$dir . "/.."` is (one) such path name. Period.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg I will not get notified of comments on other people's answers. File::Spec is a core module in Perl 5, you already have it.

Comment: @TLP : the below code doesnot return correct results. Please check :

Comment: @TLP: my $newdir = File::Spec->catdir(@dirs, File::Spec->updir()); , it return /d/..

Comment: @ShubhraGarg This is not my answer, it is Ingo's answer. When you comment here, he gets notified, so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you might want to know how to separate a directory path into a list of path elements, here is a subroutine which will separate the path.  This is for linux, so you probably want to change the path separator regex,

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#examine pathname, extract directory path
#examine pathname, extract directory path
sub dirname
{
    my($pn) = @_;
    my @p = split(/\//,$pn);    ##windows would want split(/\\/,$pn)
    if( $#p > 0 ) { pop(@p); push(@p,""); }
    else { pop(@p); push(@p,"."); }
    $pn = join('/',@p);         ##you would want join('\\',@p)
    return($pn);
};
my $dir=$ARGV[0] || "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j";
while ( $dir && length($dir)>1) {
    print "$dir\n";
    $dir = dirname($dir);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!@Ingo/@TLP : thanks to you all too :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
my $dir = "C:/mytest/mydata/mywork/mydir";
my $char = '/';
my $result = rindex($dir, $char);
$path = substr("$dir", 0,$result);
```